# Summing up amounts if one row contains a key within another sheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have two sheets in one LibreOffice Calc document:

*Sheet1*:

```
| Key | Amount  |
|-----|---------|
| ABC |    1    |
| DEF |    2    |
| GHI |    3    |
```

*Sheet2*:

```
|  Keys |
|-------|
|  ABC  |
|  XYZ  |
|  JKL  |
|  GHI  |
```

Now I'd like to add the amounts in the rows of Sheet1 but *only* where the key is contained anywhere in Sheet2. For the example above, the sum would be `4` (keys `ABC` with amount `1` and `GHI` with amount `3`).

I've been solving this with an "Advanced Filter" and `SUBTOTAL` but I'd really like a solution where I don't have to re-apply the filter when the sheets change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So the result you're looking for is just the sum?  Where does that appear (Sheet1 or Sheet2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to combine SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF.  I copied your example.

Sheet2:
[image]

Sheet1:
[image]

The formula in E2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,"="&$A$2:$A$4)*$B$2:$B$4)
```

SUMPRODUCT does an array-style calculation on the result of COUNTIF for each row on Sheet1 multiplied by the amount in column B.  Assuming the keys on Sheet2 don't contain duplicates, the count will be `1` if Sheet2 contains the key, or `0` if not.

I recommend using explicit ranges rather than simple column references (i.e., A:A).  You can pad the explicit ranges with blank rows to allow for any potential expansion you might need, and the formula will still work.  However, it takes Calc forever to evaluate entire columns.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It seems very elegant, unfortunately it gives an "Error 508". If I replace the comma with a semicolon, it turns into "#NAME?". I'm on LibreOffice 6, by the way.

Comment: @Jonas, did you try it as written first?  In `Tools | Options | LibreOffice Calc | Formula`, what are the separators shown?  Where are you located, and what locale and language settings do you use?  Error 508 indicates unbalanced parentheses.  Double check the formula.  FYI: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Error_Codes_in_Calc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm in Germany with a German version of LibreOffice. The separator in the menu you indicated shows ";" so that would explain the difference. The checkbox saying "Use english function names" is checked, however.

Comment: @Jonas, the 508 error sounds like maybe a typing mistake in entering the formula.  Check the parentheses.  Do you have Formula (same path as previous comment) set to `Excel A1`?  That follows Excel's conventions.  The LO default uses some different conventions, including the sheet name separator (I keep mine set to Excel).

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I used the wrong quotes (single instead of double) for the `=`. Now it works, thanks a lot!